# Bose QuietComfort 20 not working after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, audio, headphones

I have a mid-2012 MacBook Pro Retina, and am using QuietComfort20 headphones that previously used to work.

Now, after a clean install of OS X Yosemite, I'm unable to use the headphones, no audio comes through them at all.

When I adjust the volume use F11 or F12 I get the following

[image]

Comment: does it show the headset in System Preferences Sound output?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the Audio Output selector was "Parallels Access Audio".  When I used parallels access apparently the default output was changed, and not reverted.